# Mercurial - Hgban alternative

Tags: mercurial

We've been using [Hgban](https://bitbucket.org/jfh/hgban) to prevent unwanted pushes to get to our central repository. It stopped working for x number of Mercurial versions though, which was reported here [HgBan bug](https://bitbucket.org/jfh/hgban/issue/1/typeerror-when-upgrading-to-mercurial-232).

It seems this project is "dead" and therefore I wonder if anyone knows any other extension doing the same/similar thing (=define certain change sets to be blocked to a repository)?

Comment: What sort of filters were you using in HgBan? Block on author? On commit message? It may help in coming up with a solution.

Comment: We used hgban to block certain changesets.
If something completely wrong was pushed, we stripped those changeset from our central repo, informed all developers to get rid of the changeset locally and blocked those changesets by their id using hgban on the server if some developer missed this info.

Comment: That's an odd workflow. Normally you would just fix the bug or backout the changeset rather than edit history on all those repositories.

Comment: it's not our "workflow" but a last resort if someone has accidently pushed there develop/experimental clone to our main repo or incorrecty merged some named branches on main repo.

Comment: Perhaps you could write a `pretxnchangegroup` hook to implement this.  You'd store the hashes in a file and search the file for the revisions being pushed.  Maybe if you say what system your server runs on someone could help with that if you don't know how to do it.

Comment: yes, and i guess that's the hook hgban uses. don't know why it matters what "system" we use (we're using rhodecode on windows), it's rather lack of knowledge in python at office we are looking for a 3rd party extension.

Comment: The system matters because you don't need to do this as an extension - you can do it as a script and it is more convenient to do it as a script for the particular systems installed scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a `powershell` hook script to do what you want.  To use it you put the following lines in your central repo's `.hg\hgrc` file:

```
[hooks]
pretxnchangegroup = powershell .hg\hgban.ps1
```

The powershell script is as follows and should be put in the **.hg** folder:

```
# Default to success
$returnCode = 0

# Get the list of nodes being updated
$output = hg log -r "$Env:HG_NODE`:tip" --template "{node}`n"

# Get the list of nodes that are banned
$bannedList = Get-Content ".\.hg\hgbanlist.txt"

# Loop through the nodes
$output | Where-Object { $bannedList -contains $_  } | ForEach-Object { 
    Write-Host "Changeset $_ has been banned!"  
    $returnCode = 1
}

exit $returnCode
```

You should put a text file called **hgbanlist.txt** in your **.hg** folder containing the full hash of each of the banned revisions, one per line.  For example, here is my test file:

```
2baae3f879579979faa7aec2e32635b97e9eaff9
922ae67c4229788d21cb9c9ace1abeba38541ff9
```

This works on a pure Mercurial system - I don't know how Rhodecode would affect it, if at all.

Comment: It works just fine. Thanks! Much appricated!
Can you explain the "$Env:HG_NODE`:tip" part? I understand what it does but don't understand the syntax... Why doesn't "$HG_NODE:tip" work?

Comment: ...and by the way - thanks for showing how to write a hook in powershell. Thought we were forced to use python scripts. Makes life a LOT easier ;).

Comment: That's just how you refer to environment variables in powershell **$Env:VARIABLE_NAME**.  The ` character is the escape character in powershell which I'm using to separate the environment variable from the :.  And no problem, happy to help.